# syntax to declare array of strings (Hex commands) in c

Tags: c, arrays, hex, uart

I want to send the Hex commands below over uart to hardware attached to my mcu. I want to put them into an array and write them all at once as opposed to one at a time.

```
0x56
0x36
0x01
```

How do you declare this array in native c? Is it an array of strings?

This is the function to send the data.

```
uart_write_buff(const uart_t uart, const uint8_t *const data,
                 uint32_t len);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
unsigned char data[] = { 0x56, 0x36, 0x01 };
```

It is an array of bytes.

Or better:

```
uint8_t data[] = { 0x56, 0x36, 0x01 };
```